# SQL – при срабатывании «GEN_ID», перестает работать «distinct»

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня запрос на вставку:

```
insert into CONTRACT (DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE, ID, PROPOSAL_ID, ARCHIVE, USER_ID, CLIENT_ID, SEND_STATUS)
    select distinct(DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE), GEN_ID(GEN_ID_CONTRACT, 1), 5, 1, 1, 12, 0
    from DISTRIBUTION_PROPOSAL where PROPOSAL_ID = 5
```

Проблема в том, что при использовании генератора

```
GEN_ID(GEN_ID_CONTRACT, 1),
```

**Перестает работать «*distinct*»**, соответственно в «*CONTRACT*» вставляется больше записей, чем нужно.

Вопрос:
Как переделать запрос «*select*», чтоб заработал «*distinct*»?

Answer (score 1):

@msi, немного не так (ошибка: *no column name specified for column number 2 in derived table .*), но идея правильная,
   Кому станет интересно:

```
insert into CONTRACT (DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE, ID, PROPOSAL_ID, ARCHIVE, USER_ID, CLIENT_ID, SEND_STATUS)
    select DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE, GEN_ID(GEN_ID_CONTRACT, 1), 5, 1, 1, 12, 0
    from (
        select distinct(DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE)
        from DISTRIBUTION_PROPOSAL where PROPOSAL_ID = 5
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так:

```
insert into CONTRACT (DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE, ID, PROPOSAL_ID, ARCHIVE, USER_ID, CLIENT_ID, SEND_STATUS)
    select distinct DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE, GEN_ID(GEN_ID_CONTRACT, 1), 5, 1, 1, 12, 0
    from DISTRIBUTION_PROPOSAL where PROPOSAL_ID = 5
```

Или так:

```
insert into CONTRACT (DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE, ID, PROPOSAL_ID, ARCHIVE, USER_ID, CLIENT_ID, SEND_STATUS)
    select distinct(DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE), GEN_ID(Distinct GEN_ID_CONTRACT, 1), 5, 1, 1, 12, 0
    from DISTRIBUTION_PROPOSAL where PROPOSAL_ID = 5
```

Comment: К сожалению первый вариант работает также как и мой (см. post №1) - т.е. НЕ работает, во втором варианте, ошибка: *Token unknown - line 2, column 52. Distinct.*

Comment: Gen_id возвращает уникальное число, вот и записей больше. Может быть убрать его и сделать это поле autoincrement и вообще не использовать в инсерте - само вычислится и заполнится.

Comment: "Не использовать" - можно, ведь это внутренняя процедура по сути, тогда восспользуюсь *for select...*

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
insert into CONTRACT (DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE, PROPOSAL_ID, ARCHIVE, USER_ID, CLIENT_ID, SEND_STATUS, ID)
    select *, GEN_ID(GEN_ID_CONTRACT, 1) 
    from (select distinct DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE, 5, 1, 1, 12, 0
    from DISTRIBUTION_PROPOSAL where PROPOSAL_ID = 5) X;
```